# Concatenate specific combinations of files from list into subdirectories

Tags: bash, cat

I want to cat a large amount of specific combinations of files together from a list of 10 files into their corresponding subdirectories. I have a main directory with 126 subdirectories that are called

> CrHfMoNbN, CrHfMoTaN, CrHfMoTiN, ... , TiVWZrN

and so on, basically one subdirectory for every combination from the following list that is sorted alphabetically, with an appended "**N**":

> CrHfMoNb CrHfMoTa CrHfMoTi CrHfMoV CrHfMoW CrHfMoZr CrHfNbTa CrHfNbTi CrHfNbV CrHfNbW CrHfNbZr CrHfTaTi CrHfTaV CrHfTaW CrHfTaZr CrHfTiV CrHfTiW CrHfTiZr CrHfVW CrHfVZr CrHfWZr CrMoNbTa CrMoNbTi CrMoNbV CrMoNbW CrMoNbZr CrMoTaTi CrMoTaV CrMoTaW CrMoTaZr CrMoTiV CrMoTiW CrMoTiZr CrMoVW CrMoVZr CrMoWZr CrNbTaTi CrNbTaV CrNbTaW CrNbTaZr CrNbTiV CrNbTiW CrNbTiZr CrNbVW CrNbVZr CrNbWZr CrTaTiV CrTaTiW CrTaTiZr CrTaVW CrTaVZr CrTaWZr CrTiVW CrTiVZr CrTiWZr CrVWZr HfMoNbTa HfMoNbTi HfMoNbV HfMoNbW HfMoNbZr HfMoTaTi HfMoTaV HfMoTaW HfMoTaZr HfMoTiV HfMoTiW HfMoTiZr HfMoVW HfMoVZr HfMoWZr HfNbTaTi HfNbTaV HfNbTaW HfNbTaZr HfNbTiV HfNbTiW HfNbTiZr HfNbVW HfNbVZr HfNbWZr HfTaTiV HfTaTiW HfTaTiZr HfTaVW HfTaVZr HfTaWZr HfTiVW HfTiVZr HfTiWZr HfVWZr MoNbTaTi MoNbTaV MoNbTaW MoNbTaZr MoNbTiV MoNbTiW MoNbTiZr MoNbVW MoNbVZr MoNbWZr MoTaTiV MoTaTiW MoTaTiZr MoTaVW MoTaVZr MoTaWZr MoTiVW MoTiVZr MoTiWZr MoVWZr NbTaTiV NbTaTiW NbTaTiZr NbTaVW NbTaVZr NbTaWZr NbTiVW NbTiVZr NbTiWZr NbVWZr TaTiVW TaTiVZr TaTiWZr TaVWZr TiVWZr

This list is stored in the main directory in the file `list.txt`. The files that need to be concatenated are also stored in this directory and they are called: `file_Cr`, `file_Hf`, `file_Mo`, `file_N`, `file_Nb`, `file_Ta`, `file_Ti`, `file_V`, `file_W`, `file_Zr`, so there is one file for every chemical element. What I need to do is concatenate these files, so that for every permutation of elements the corresponding files are put together and stored in their subfolder. The crucial part is concatenating them in the right order, which is the following: **always** first `file_N`, then the files of the metals in the order of the list (which is alphabetical). For example in the subfolder

> CrHfMoNbN

the order is `file_N` -> `file_Cr` -> `file_Hf` -> `file_Mo` -> `file_Nb`, in the folder

> NbTiVWN

the order is `file_N` -> `file_Nb` -> `file_Ti` -> `file_V` ->  `file_W`. The resulting file should always be named `POTCAR`.

Comment: See [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for "How do I do X?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069/4154375).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`egrep -wo "^PREFIX" list.txt | xargs -I '{}' mv {} \file_PREFIX`

for each type of file. Im not sure what information is specified in the `list.txt' file, where are the file really located, what is the pattern of the names you've given to your files and directories and so on.

you can try and modify this line according to your exact needs.